# Alterar path tabela vinculada ms access

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Tenho 2 banco de dados que para serem utilizados em uma aplicação copio-os do servidor na máquina local do usuário. Entre esses dois bancos tenho uma tabela vinculada, preciso que quando copie para a máquina local, atualize o endereço dessa tabela vinculada.

Vi alguns fóruns com vb mas não achei nada com c#, somente VBA...

https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/160138-resolvido-codigo-vba-para-definir-path-das-tabelas-vinculadas/

Comment: Você pode executar esse VBA como uma macro no Access e chamar essa macro pelo C#

Comment: Obrigado cara, mas consegui pelo c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// the following code requires that the project have a COM reference to:
// "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library"

// create the DBEngine object
var dbe = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine();

// open the local database file containing the linked table
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(fileNamePainelGerencialTo);

// create a TableDef object for the linked table we want to update
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.TableDef tbd = db.TableDefs["tblPendencia"];

// update the .Connect property with the full path to the remote database
tbd.Connect = ";DATABASE=" + fileNamePainelGerencialPendenciasTo;

// refresh the table link
tbd.RefreshLink();

// create a TableDef object for the linked table we want to update
tbd = db.TableDefs["tblPendenciaBaixa"];

// update the .Connect property with the full path to the remote database
tbd.Connect = ";DATABASE=" + fileNamePainelGerencialPendenciasTo;

// refresh the table link
tbd.RefreshLink();
```